# Count multiple occurrence of multiple fields in a column corresponding to another attribute

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I am having a table having fields as (NAME FRUIT TIME)

```
|   NAME |  FRUIT |  TIME |
|--------|--------|-------|
|   AJAY |  MANGO | 10:10 |
| SACHIN |  APPLE | 12:00 |
|    RAJ |  MANGO | 10:00 |
|   AJAY |  MANGO | 12:00 |
|   AJAY |  MANGO | 11:00 |
|   AJAY |  APPLE | 12:00 |
|    RAJ | BANANA | 12:00 |
|   AJAY | BANANA | 12:00 |
| SACHIN | BANANA |  2:00 |
| SACHIN |  MANGO | 12:00 |
|    RAJ |  MANGO | 12:00 |
| SACHIN |  APPLE | 12:00 |
|   AJAY |  APPLE | 12:00 |
|   AJAY |  APPLE | 12:00 |
```

Now I want to get output from the above table like this:

```
|   NAME | MANGOCOUNT | APPLECOUNT | BANANACOUNT |
|--------|------------|------------|-------------|
|   AJAY |          3 |          3 |           1 |
|    RAJ |          2 |          0 |           1 |
| SACHIN |          1 |          2 |           1 |
```

I tried `UNION` like this:

```
SELECT NAME, COUNT(*) AS MANGOCOUNT FROM FRUIT_EAT 
 WHERE FRUIT='MANGO'  GROUP BY NAME 
UNION ALL 
SELECT NAME, COUNT(*) AS APPLECOUNT FROM FRUIT_EAT 
 WHERE FRUIT='APPLE' GROUP BY NAME 
UNION ALL 
SELECT NAME, COUNT(*) AS BANANACOUNT FROM FRUIT_EAT 
 WHERE FRUIT='BANANA' GROUP BY NAME;
```

I am getting result as

```
NAME        MANGOCOUNT
AJAY           3
RAJ            2
SACHIN         1
AJAY           3
RAJ            0
SACHIN         2
AJAY           1
RAJ            1
SACHIN         1
```

I am not understanding my mistake. If you please help me out?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Markdown Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to know how to format your post. Also have a look at [the edit revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18798226/revisions) of your post after my edit.

Comment: thanks hims056 for edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use `UNION` for that. You can do this using `SUM()` function and `CASE` statement like this:

```
SELECT Name
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Fruit = 'Mango' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MangoCount
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Fruit = 'Apple' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AppleCount
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Fruit = 'Banana' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BananaCount
  FROM MyTable
 GROUP BY Name;
```

You can also use this dynamic query:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(CASE WHEN `Fruit` = ''',
      `Fruit`,
      ''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `',
      `Fruit`, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM MyTable;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Name, ', @sql,'
                     FROM MyTable
                    GROUP BY Name
                  ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Output:

```
|   NAME | MANGOCOUNT | APPLECOUNT | BANANACOUNT |
|--------|------------|------------|-------------|
|   AJAY |          3 |          3 |           1 |
|    RAJ |          2 |          0 |           1 |
| SACHIN |          1 |          2 |           1 |
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd3ca/1)

Comment: YES ITS WORKING!! THANK YOU!!
CAN IT BE ANSWERED BY USING UNION?

Comment: @codemaniac143 - Your expected output can not be achieved by using `UNION` (why to use it when it is not required). Please don't use capital letters.

Comment: yes, thanks I will keep in mind all the things while asking question afterwords